# Is it possible to signup new user in parse.com?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to signup a new user manually on parse.com from IOS code . I need this because i want to add 3-4 extra fields on signup. Here is the code i am trying, but it is not inserting the data into user class :

```
    PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"User"];
    [testObject setObject:@"bar" forKey:@"username"];
    [testObject setObject:@"bar" forKey:@"password"];
    [testObject setObject:@"1111111" forKey:@"additional"];
    [testObject setObject:@"bar@123.com" forKey:@"email"];
    [testObject setObject:@"2323233" forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
    [testObject setObject:@"12,california" forKey:@"address"];
    [testObject save];
```

Any help please. What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: To add MORE fields to PFUser, you must (1) first create the user in the normal way. (2) in a SEPARATE CALL, send up the other fields. That's the only way.

Comment: @JoeBlow you don't need to split it into 2 requests...

Comment: You must use two calls. First you create the new PFUser, then you add the extra fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE - THIS ANSWER DOES NOT USE THE STANDARD PFUser CLASS IN PARSE.

Essentially it does not work. If you're not using the actual PFUser class, nothing in Parse works (example, email verification, password reset, account handling, blah blah)

To add extra fields using PFUser is very simple: (1) create the user in the normal way. (2) **in a separate call**, send up the other fields.  Very often you will also have an image (like a user avatar) - send that up separately in another cal.

---

After a lot of RnD i found this as a solution to my question. I am sharing it here so that it would be useful to others also

```
-(void)userSignUp:(NSDictionary*)userData {
    //username,password,additional,email,profilePic

    ADUser *user = [[ADUser alloc] init];
    user.username = [userData valueForKey:@"username"];
    user.password = [userData valueForKey:@"password"];
    user.email = [userData valueForKey:@"email"];
    user.phone = [userData valueForKey:@"phone"];
    user.additional = [userData valueForKey:@"name"];

    PFUser *usr = (PFUser*)user;

    [usr signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error) // Something went wrong
         {
             // Display an alert view to show the error message
             UIAlertView *alertView =
             [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"]
                                    message:nil
                                   delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
             [alertView show];

             // Bring the keyboard back up, user will probably need to change something
             //[usernameField becomeFirstResponder];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"success");
             [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

         }

     }];
}
```

Comment: You should use @LostInTheTrees answer, the reason yours didn't work was because you weren't using the PFUser class.

Comment: I tried using that also but it didn't work for me. What i was actually  looking was the signUpInBackgroundWithBlock method. This is the only way i found to register with custom number of fields .  @LostInTheTrees answer was correct in a way but doesnt fulfill my requirement as the title of this question indicates. But i am really thankful for LostInTheTrees's answer.

Comment: You could always assign the custom fields after the sign up was successful, as in within the `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` code block

Comment: Do not do this -- it is not using the PFUser class.  it's just making a class that happens to be called "user" - so it does not function as the PFUser class, at all !

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
user.username = @"my name";
user.password = @"my pass";
user.email = @"email@example.com";

// other fields can be set just like with PFObject
```

-Bob

Comment: It wont allow Phon number to be added this way. So first we need to subclass the PFUser & then we can add additional fields. Please correct me if i am wrong here.

Comment: You are wrong. "other fields can be set just like with PFObject"

Answer (score 2):

Subclass PFUser Like this

User.h

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface User : PFUser <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *nickName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;

@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile* image;


@end
```

User.m

```
#import "User.h"

@implementation User
@dynamic nickName, email, type;

+(void)load {
  [self registerSubclass];
}

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
  return @"_User";
}

@end
```

Then use following code to signup:

```
User *user = [PFUser user];
user.nickName = @"Alpha";
user.username=username;
user.password=@"0000";

[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Signup Success");
     }
     else{
         NSLog(@"Signup Error : %@ ", error);
     }
 }];
```

That's how we use PFUser to signup. You can always add extra fields to PFUser class. Subclassing provides you this feature.